# Why does my HTML5 video loop (and never trigger the ended event) even though I'm telling it not to?

Tags: html, html5-video

I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="video1" preload="metadata" width="1024" height="576" loop="false">
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <script>
        var video = document.getElementById('video1');
        video.addEventListener("ended", function() {
            alert('Ended');
        });

        video.play();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In chrome and firefox the video loops endlessly.  Attaching listeners to the `pause` or `ended` events show these never actually get fired.

I need to know when a video has ended (and I need it to stop on ending).  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16):

Apparently `loop='false'` still causes it to loop, and you have to completely remove the loop attribute to prevent looping.  Ended never gets called if the video is set to loop.

Comment: Have you ever had an instance of the video continuing to loop even after the loop attribute was removed?  I think there must be some rogue code somewhere on the site I'm working on that's auto-restarting the video, because getting rid of loop didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
    video.addEventListener("ended",function(){
        console.log("the video is end");
    },false);
```

Comment: I'm aware that's how you attach the ended thread, however that event never fires in my example.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use ontimeupdate and currentTime